# -50 points for serial upvoting?

Tags: bug, voting

Is there a bug in the system? Why did I lose 50 points for serial up-voting.  Some of the voting looks strange too, like it has it was voted at the same exact time when in fact some of my questions or answers were posted on different days.  Can someone look into this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one sense you didn't really "lose" 50 points — instead, you got 50 points that you shouldn't have gotten, and that was corrected.  Someone voted on too many of your posts in too short a time, which is indicative of a sock-puppet account or a voting ring.

These votes might have been legitimate, but I would guess that it's unlikely to be reversed, since you can't infer intent from nothing more than a sequence of votes.  Then again you own a significant percentage of the posts so far on this site so it might have been inevitable.  Hopefully an SE employee stops by and can tell you if anything will happen.

To prevent this, everyone should be careful to spread out their votes.  Don't go through one user's profile and vote on all their posts, for example.

Comment: thanks for the input, just curious, what is a sock-puppet account? and what benefit do they get from doing this?

Comment: @xaisoft A sock puppet is a secondary account someone creates to vote on their own posts.  Gets them more rep.  There are automatic checks in place to catch and revert activity that's typical for sock puppets, so another user may have been erroneously flagged for voting a lot on your posts.  Again, it's hard to say whether the votes (your rep) will be reinstated but hopefully they can tell what the right course of action is.

Comment: If what you say is correct ("These votes might have been legitimate, but it's unlikely to be reversed"), then it is indeed a bug is the system. I guess we will need a better system to detect bot activity, sock-puppet accounts, and voting rings. But that's already difficult and is likely to get even more difficult with improvements in ML/AI.